# Interview Questions (in C#)

Tags: java, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

So I was given a small program to write, which I did well but then I was asked the following and I was a bit confused.

What are the values of the following?

// I told them that they would get an error as they are not initialized, so they are pointing to some address in memory...

```
int a;
Object b;
int d = a;
bool c;
```

if in Java, replace the last line with

```
boolean c;
```

Please let me know the correct answer to this as I am sure it will be brought up again. Thank you :)

Comment: Why the Java tag? Do you want to know the values in Java also?

Comment: Presuming the C# answers below are correct, there is no difference. The Java defaults are `0`, `null`, and `false` also.

Comment: @FarmBoy: In Java, this can compile.  In C#, it can't.

Comment: @SLaks, sorry, I wasn't thinking about the compilation issue, since your original answer didn't mention it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .Net CLR initializes all fields and locals to their default values.
In your case, that's `0`, `null`, and `false`.

However, this code will not compile under any circumstances.

Inside a method, C# will not allow you to use uninitialized locals, so `d = b` will not compile.
As instance fields, C# does not allow you to use `this` until you're inside the constructor, so `d = a` will not compile in a field initializer.

As static fields, this would compile, but the `static` keyword is missing.

---

In Java, all of this is also true, except that Java does allow you to use `this` in field initializers.
Therefore, this code is valid in Java as instance fields.

Comment: Thank you all, These are the values I gave them altough the program will require us to initialize them.

Answer (score 1):

In C# the default value for an `int` is 0. An `Object` is null. And a `bool` is false.

A simple google found the asnwer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I give you a vote :)

Comment: It's true *but* C# is defending you from a common C error by saying if you try to use two uninitialised variables (even though they both have  .CLR default values) , then it's a bug.

Comment: ++ and it saves you form the unlikely but nether-the-less possible decision in the future that these values might change.

Answer (score 1):

a == 0, 
b == null,
d == 0,
c == false

Comment: Thank you, I give you a vote :)